# Como obtener los valores seleccionado de un CheckedListBox en c#

Tags: c#

Vengo con una interrogante ya que no tengo idea de como poder capturar los datos almacenados en el siguiente checkedlistbox que esta conformado en este ejemplo de 6 opciones para poder tildar en realidad son como 20, cada opción de selección es un campo en una tabla que permite valores null o por defecto la opcion seleccionada.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como podría o como debería poder capturar estos datos para almacenarlos en una variable temporal para posteriormente en un método poder guardar la selección correspondiente.

De antemano agradezco su ayuda.

Comment: Tal vez con [`CheckedItems`](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox.checkeditems#system-windows-forms-checkedlistbox-checkeditems). No sé bien a qué te refieres. Podrías estar hablando de Windows Forms, ASP.NET u otra cosa